# Как преобразить объект в порядке возрастания по его свойству, которые является числовым типом

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, числовые-последовательности

У меня есть массив, в котором есть объекты, содержащая: id, obj(объект), timestamp
Хочу преобразовать массив в поряке последовательности по св-ву timestamp

```
arr = [{id: 123, obj: {...}, timestamp: 1658484500}, {id: 1233, obj: {...}, timestamp: 1658000500}]
```

Повторюсь, хочу чтобы объекты были в массиве arr в порядке возрастания в зависимости от timestamp.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Используй метод [`sort(тут_хитрый_компаратор)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так, (в массив добавлены объекты с маленьким TimeStamp, для наглядности)

```
const arr = [
    { id: 123, obj: {}, timestamp: 1000 },
    { id: 123, obj: {}, timestamp: 240 },
    { id: 123, obj: {}, timestamp: 100 },
    { id: 123, obj: {}, timestamp: 1658484500 },
    { id: 1233, obj: {}, timestamp: 1658000500 },
]; 

arr.sort((prev, next) => prev.timestamp - next.timestamp);
console.log(arr);
/*[
 { id: 123, obj: {}, timestamp: 100 },
  { id: 123, obj: {}, timestamp: 240 },
  { id: 123, obj: {}, timestamp: 1000 },
  { id: 1233, obj: {}, timestamp: 1658000500 },
  { id: 123, obj: {}, timestamp: 1658484500 }
]
*/
```